# Inject external prior distribution to my dataset

Tags: machine-learning, classification, probability, boosting

**Input:**

1. External Information - distribution between the `feature_i` & `binary_target`
2. Internal Dataset - tabular data. `#sample_size` is very low when `feature_i` > constant.

**How I can inject the prior knowledge [1] into the internal dataset [2]?**

I thought of two methodologies:

1. Use `feature_i` outside the model - using the prior knowledge and `feature_i` to beta distribution. Problem: assumption of independence + how I can ensemble the two models?
2. Use `feature_i` inside the model - synthesize data (or give extra weights) when `feature_i` > constant. Problem: I'm afraid the model will overfit, because of the synthesized data.

I would love to hear thoughts, thanks